# Terminology of execute, call, run, and render

Tags: terminology

I'm new to python/javascript/html coding, and I keep getting in trouble for using the wrong terminology.  What is the implied meaning for each of the following terms?

- Execute
- Call
- Run
- Render

And are there other similar groups of terms that mean similar things that have important differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alot of programming is just fancy terminology. Sometimes it is un-needed, but we use it so we can be more *specific*. This is helpful because programming requires a lot of accuracy and *explicit* detail.

In your example, the terms can frequently mean the same thing. Instead of asking yourself what those terms mean, understand they have similar meanings and instead ask yourself, "where would I use these?".

- In Linux, *execute* is a term that describes a user who can run files.
- In many IDE's, *run* is a term describing an action when you test your
  code.
- In anything involving graphics, *render* can be used to describe the
  process of generating a *model* or *scene*.
- The term *call* is typically used when you refer to a function you wish to invoke in order to perform a certain task.

So yes, these terms all really have the same - or similar meanings. The difference is instead when they are used. And because we use them in different situations, it allows us to distinguish them from each other.

Answer (score 1):

*Execute*, *call*, and *run* are used in various contexts and can mean different things or sometimes the same thing.

*Render* is kind of different, as I would only use it related to graphics. The Browser renders the HTML, or 3d software like PovRay render an image. But this term is not so close to the other three terms.